# Can't manipulate inputs in EditForm.aspx with jQuery

Tags: jquery, selection, sharepoint-2013, document-ready, onload-event

I try to manipulated the “EditForm.aspx” of a list in my site collection (SharePoint 2013).
I want some input fields to be hidden based on the users permission level.
To realize this, I added an editor webpart to the standard form of the EditForm.aspx with the following code:

```
<script src="https://test-teamshare.zeiss.org/minimal/05011/Libs/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://test-teamshare.zeiss.org/minimal/05011/Libs/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideInputFields");

    function hideInputFields() {
        $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetRolesAndPermissionsForCurrentUser",
        async: false,
        completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            var userPerm = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Permissions").attr("Value");
            var userRole = $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("Role").attr("Name");


            if(jQuery(".ms-formbody").find(input[title='Dokumentennummer'])) {
                alert("has found the Fiels");
            }

            if(userRole = "Vollzugriff") {

            }
        }
        });
    }
</script>
```

unfortunately  this doesn’t (at least fully) work. The part with the user permission works well, but I am not able to manipulate the input fields.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to replace the “document.ready()” with “_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()” but this also doesn’t help.

Then I read something about the “Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)” but I don’t really understand that concept based on the information I have about this.

Can anyone help?

Thank your very much

Benjamin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is in find
You use title, you should use ID. Just be careful when the id incudes '$'.
Use firebug to see if (jQuery(".ms-formbody").find(input[title='Dokumentennummer'] returns anything.